# Django simple annotation across two models

Tags: django, annotations, django-queryset

I've got three models, User, Achievement, and UserAchievement:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    ...

class Achievement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class UserAchievement(models.Model):
    # Use a lazy reference to avoid circular import issues
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    achievement = models.ForeignKey(Achievement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'd like to annotate Users with a 'points' column that sums up the total points they've earned for all their achievements as listed in the UserAchievement table.

But clearly I'm not fully up to speed with how annotations work.  When I try:

```
users = User.objects.annotate(points=Sum('userachievement__achievement__points'))
for u in users:
   print(u.email, u.points)
```

It crashes with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dylan/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-E23dvZwD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/dylan/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-E23dvZwD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/dylan/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-E23dvZwD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 78, in __iter__
setattr(obj, attr_name, row[col_pos])
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: Does your User model already have a property named points?

Comment: You can use a ManyToManyField from User to Achievement using UserAchievement 
 as a through table to simplify your queries

Comment: No.  I'm hoping to add that to the table by means of annotation:  it's got to find all the UserAchievement records that belong to the user and sum up the points of the achievement in each of those records.  The sum would be added to the User model.

Comment: The ManyToManyField idea is an interesting one.  Can you show me what you mean more specifically?

Comment: Add an answer with information about ManyToManyField and through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) from `User` to `Achievement` using `UserAchievement` as a through table to simplify your queries

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    achievements = models.ManyToManyField('Achievement', through='UserAchievement')
    ...
```

This can be used like so for annotations

```
User.objects.annotate(points=Sum('achievements__points'))
```

And if you have an instance of user

```
user.achievements.all()
```

As for the error, I am convinced you have a property on your User model named points

Comment: Amazing!  That not only did the trick, but you were absolutely right about the property.  I could have sworn I'd removed that.  The ManyToManyField - through thing is going to help a lot going ahead.